# Azure AD or IdentityServer with Web API, understanding the concepts

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory, identityserver4, restful-authentication

Be warned possibly noob question ahead.

I'm a little unsure where exactly Azure AD or IdentityServer is supposed to fit in in the overall communication flow.

Here is a scenario that I often face.

Some "dumb" client (e.g. a Windows App that can't use external assemblies or some JavaScript in a web app) has to contact my Web API which will then contact other APIs or other resources.

If I want to try and implement either Azure AD or IdentityServer as a means of authentication and authorization in the Web API, I don't see that this can be done in any other way, than it has to be the Web API that communicates with Azure AD or IdentityServer as the client doesn't have the ability to do so due to the lack of required assemblies.

If this assumption is not correct, then how would I do this?

If it is correct however, then what means of security is there between the client and the Web API other than communicating over HTTPS when the client has to send it's credentials to the Web API, so the Web API can authenticate and authorize the user against either Azure AD or IdentityServer?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements correctly, then you are able to change the client Windows app, but unable to add external assemblies to it? So you would not be able to add the ADAL NuGet package to it.

You can still use Azure AD authentication - it **is** possible, but not trivial, to implement the client code yourself.

Or you can, as you already mentioned, pass the user's credentials to the Web API somehow, and then use that to have the Web API do authentication towards Azure AD on behalf of the user. There is a [sample app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless/) which shows how to use username/password credentials.

This however, goes against the whole OAuth/OpenIdConnect mindset, where your app should never know the user's credentials.

Comment: Correct, the client (here the Windows app) can't add nuget packeges or any other kind of assemblies other then those already in the .NET framework.

Comment: So to be sure I get this right - If I can't use external libraries (not part of .NET framework libraries) on the client side of this (this could be a Dynamics NAV or similar), then I should look to other means of securing the communication between client and my Web API?

Comment: If you can add any source code you write, then you can implement the auth code directly. Otherwise, you need to find another way. Obviously use TLS (https) when communicating between client and Web API.

Answer (score 0):

Here:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oidc.md

Be careful with trying to use the most recent version of the Azure AD endpoint (just don't use version 2.0, they shot themselves in the foot by excluding all Azure AD webapp registrations & by "securing" web APIs by making them only available to apps with the same appid - as far as I'm concerned, it's unusable until they fix those two issues) - see the "[!NOTE]" near the top of that linked page for the v2.0 limitations.